# JSONFIeld(null=True): Is allowing null bad practice?

Tags: django

It's my first time working with Django's `JSON` fields. When going through examples I usually see the field implementations that set the default to an empty object.

However, for my purposes, I'd prefer to allow the field to be `None` as well. Since all the examples set a default, I'm not sure if allowing `null` will yield any negative consequences I'm unaware of currently.

Comment: It means there are *two* representations for `None`, which is usually not a good idea.

Comment: You mean `None` and {} both serve as `None`? I'm building an API with Django and Javascript interprets None and `{}` quite differently (`{}` is truthy, `None` is falsy)

Comment: no, `NULL` in the database, and the string `'null'` in the database  are both equivalent to `NULL`. For some databases, behind the curtains this is a simple VARCHAR field where Django simply serializes and deserializes. So you are still allowing `None`.

Comment: Hm, I using Postgres and can't confirm this. Normal fields and JSON fields have the same representation for `null=True`values.

Comment: of course, because for very long, PostgreSQL was the only database with JSON support. The point is that even if `null=False`, you can still for most database backends *use* `None`. Since behind the curtains Django has *not* constructed a JSON field (since some of these database did/do not have a JsonField), so Django creates a VARCHAR, and performs the (de)serialization itself. But since it is a VARCHAR, you can use the string `'null'` (not the database `NULL`), and this will still derserialize to `None`.

Comment: Ok, got it. But would there be any reason not to use `null=True` for a Postgres database?

Comment: the idea of an ORM is *not* to focus on a specific database, but write "queries" in a way that you can easily translate these to a different database. This thus should mean that you can develop on an SQLite database for example, and run it on another database in production.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining this. I'm still not 100% convinced. So, basically, the only downside would be that in some databases I would have a value of "null" (which could confuse devs) - but the Django ORM would take care of this automatically by parsing it to a `None` value. To me, the potential confusion is a non-issue since I'll stick to PG & the interoperability between databases is handled by Django automatically - so also a non-issue.